# How to Checkbox and label style only with CSS

Tags: css, checkbox, label

somebody can help me with how can I design checkbox and label like on the shared picture only with css : Hover effect, normal and when is checked with blue inside

I am trying to do but I can't.

Comment: Could you please paste the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)/minimal relevant code into your question?

Answer (score 3):

The below should give you a decent starting point. You want to style a related `label` and its `:before` pseudo element dependant on the `:checked` state of a preceding checkbox, which is hidden itself.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44tFj/)

[And a revised version](http://jsfiddle.net/44tFj/1/), with slightly more complex CSS

HTML

```
<input id='check1' type='checkbox'>
<label for='check1'>Click me!</label>
```

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked +label:before {
    background:blue;
}
label {
    color:blue;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    height:1em;
    width:1em;
    border:1px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, and about hover effect I can do with label:hover or when mouse is over and text and checkbox both change color ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fully adjusted version:

[image]

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jzelenkov/G643a/)

**Source code is taken directly from @SW4 and he should get the credit.**

HTML:

```
<input id='check1' type='checkbox'>
<label for='check1'>Click me!</label>
<br/>
<input id='check2' type='checkbox'>
<label for='check2'>Click me!</label>
<br/>
<input id='check3' type='checkbox'>
<label for='check3'>Click me!</label>
<br/>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked +label:before {
    background:#01A6DE;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 0;
}
label {
    color:black;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:20px;
}
label:hover {
    color:#01A6DE;
}
label:hover:before {
    border:1px solid #01A6DE;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    height:13px;
    width:13px;
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```